# Can I skip mercurial pre-commit hooks like in git?

Tags: git, mercurial, hook, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I want to do something like `git commit --no-verify` but with mercurial. Are any ways to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the [`hg help config` documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hgrc):

> ... Multiple hooks can be run for the same action by appending a suffix to the action.  **Overriding a site-wide hook can be done by changing its value or setting it to an empty string.**  Hooks can be prioritized by adding a prefix of "priority." to the hook name on a new line and setting the priority. The default priority is 0.

(emphasis mine).  While this refers to "system-wide hooks", it works for in-repository hooks as well:

```
$ sed -n '/hooks/,+1p' .hg/hgrc
[hooks]
pre-commit = ./foo.sh
$ cat foo.sh
#! /bin/sh
echo foo
exit 1
$ hg commit
foo
abort: pre-commit hook exited with status 1
```

Obviously my pre-commit hook is working.  Now to defeat it:

```
$ hg --config hooks.pre-commit= commit
nothing changed
```

(there was nothing to commit; overriding the pre-commit hook worked).

You will, of course, need to know which specific hook(s) you want to override, since there may be more than one pre-commit hook.